# How can i submit all cloned forms?

Tags: jquery

I have one form, and I created a script to duplicate this form when you click at a specific link.

I used the event clone() to do that, and its working fine.

Now i want to create a button that submits all the created Forms and inserts all the information inside a table.

I just want to know how can i do that and Which events do i need to use.

My jquery code is really simple

```
$(".add").click(function () {
      $('.offer:first').clone().find("input:text").val('').end().appendTo('.job');

    });
```

Comment: We might need some HTML.

Comment: i just want to understand the logic, the html is very basic, i have one form and one input box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use ajax, that way you can collect all of the form data in one place.

```
var forms[0] = $('.offer:first');
var formId = 1;


$(".add").click(function () {
      $forms[formId] = $('.offer:first').clone();
      $forms[formId].find("input:text").val('').end().appendTo('.job');
      formId++;
});

$(".submit").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault;
      for (i=0; i<count($forms);i++) {
           values[i] = $forms[i].serializeArray();
      }

      $.ajax(
           url: "submitScript.php",
           data : {values:values},
           success: function() {
                for (i=1; i<count($forms);i++) {
                    forms[i].delete();
                }
           }  
     );
});
```

Comment: I missed a ); at the end of my $.ajax call, I've just added it.

Comment: the submit button would be outside of your form structure otherwise it would fir this function x number of times

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are doing this is wrong, you need to clone only a group of inputs then append to a unique form, you don't need to clone and make multiple forms.

```
<form id="unique_form">
    <div id="inputs_to_clone">
       <input type="text" name="input_name">
       <input type="text" name="input2">
    </div>
</form>
```

so now you can do

```
$(".add").click(function () {
     $('#inputs_to_clone').clone().find("input:text").val('').end().appendTo('#unique_form');
});
```

And you can submit your unique form.

Comment: I don't think that would work because your unique form would contain x number of inputs with the same name.

Comment: When you have multiple inputs with the same name this will be handled as an array of values in several languages such as php, c# or others

Comment: I always thought you had to give the name a [] on the end for it to be  processed by php and not overwritten. eg name="myInput[]"

Comment: Of course, anyway you can alternatively generate a new element with the name you want, the solution proposed by you generate an Ajax request for every form, that it's not good I you want a fast response.

Comment: agreed, my way will be slower.  I'm not doing an ajax request for each form though, I'm collecting the data from every form and then create a single ajax request for all of the data. It would still be slow due to having to traverse every from.

Comment: you just made me realise I didn't say that the submit button is out side of the forms so you have one button that submits every form. Sorry for the confusion.